# matching individual characters in a palindrome with javascript?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I can match to see if a string of numbers is or isn't a palindrome using a .reverse().join on the string, and get a true or false like:

```
var isPalindrome = function (string) {
  if (string == string.split('').reverse().join('')) {
    alert(string + ' is palindrome.');
  }
  else {
    alert(string + ' is not palindrome.');
  }
}
```

However, I need to figure out how many numbers match a palindrome pattern, not the whole word.  For instance, if the user types in '112231' the return would be 2, '1234321' is 3, '4010220804' is 4, and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Are you searching for all palindromes in a given string? And if that is so, how about intersections. Like finding 2x `232` and the full string `0123245423210`?

Comment: I am trying to detect if the first character matches with the last character, the second matches the second to last character, the third matches the third to last character and so on.  For instance, in the string '12859841', only the '1' and the '8' are in the same place backwards and forwards.

Comment: `function(string){ let count = 0; for(let i=0, j=string.length-1; i<j; ) if(string.charAt(i++) === string.charAt(j--)) ++count; return count; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the reversed and normal string and iterated over their indices since they should be the same length. I just created a counter and returned an alert if it wasn't a full palindrome.

```
 var isPalindrome = function(string) {
  let letters = string.split('');
  let reversed = Array.from(letters).reverse();
  if (string == reversed.join('')) {
    alert(string + ' is palindrome.');
    return true;
  } else {
    let matches = 0;
    for (let letter_index in letters) {
        if (letters[letter_index] === reversed[letter_index]) {
          matches++;
      }  
    }
    alert(matches);
  }
}
```

```js
 var isPalindrome = function(string) {
  let letters = string.split('');
  let reversed = Array.from(letters).reverse();
  if (string == reversed.join('')) {
    alert(string + ' is palindrome.');
    return true;
  } else {
    let matches = 0;
    for (let letter_index in letters) {
        if (letters[letter_index] === reversed[letter_index]) {
          matches++;
      }  
    }
    alert(matches);
    return matches;
  }
}

isPalindrome('tacocat');
isPalindrome('tacocatat');
isPalindrome('banana');
isPalindrome('anana');
```